# Can't diagnose: Background position different on page open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax, parallax.js

I am using parallax.js on my web page.

http://www.edizarca.com/karpaz/ (page has been now updated, parallax is remove until a feaseable solution found)

But open the page and keep refreshing. Sometimes the background image starts eerie(off position). Ive tested both in chrome and firefox and I can't figure out why its doing this.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: off topic: the hovereffect "white font on yellow background" is horrible...

Comment: I think it looks good :p but anyway, got any better color suggestions for a better effect?

Comment: offtopic: The datail is the hover style of the petition anchor at the top. It turns white while the background is yellow. You don't necesarily need to change its color, you can try an effect with the background or the border or something along those lines. Yellow is ok, the details is just that hover.

Comment: Alright :) I'll look into that once I get priority coding done.

Comment: You could try setting an explizit initial y-offset for your parallax.

Comment: @EdizArca It doesn't... remove the color and add something like an underline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The following is what I've discovered by inspection.*

parallax.js stores the initial top offset of the element to which it is applied. This value is stored in a variable called `firstTop`. The `background-position` will be placed based on the value of `firstTop` and the current scroll position, in such way that `background-position` will only be able to reach 0 if `firstTop` is 0 [for example if `firstTop` is 96 `background-position` will not be less of 67].

Note: more about 96 later.

That's right, `firstTop` is not always 0, form time to time I manage to get to a non-zero value. I suspect it has something to do with browser cache.

So, from where does the value `firstTop` come from? Here is the code:

```
//get the starting position of each element to have parallax applied to it      
$this.each(function(){
    firstTop = $this.offset().top;
});
```

Where offset is a function defined in JQuery. In the particular case of querying an element it will fall back to getBoundingClientRect. So, if the problem where there, it would be a bug of the browser...

So, to look in another direction... the value I've got is 96 and it is just [sometimes] after a cache clean. At the break point there is nothing rendered yet except for a gray background an a scroll bar... but if I have not cleared the cache at the break point the layout of the page is visible.

About 96, it is the height of the div with id "header". By the moment I hit the break point the height differs, depending of if I have cleaned the cache. If I have cleared cache it is [sometimes] 96, if have not it is 150 (but now the div with id "wrapper" has `position: relative` and it's top offset is 0).

*So.... how do we explain this behaviour?*

The file `style.css` of course. If the cache is invalidated the browser has to download it again, meanwhile it will go to execute javascript. If it reads the position of the div with id "wrapped" before the css is applied then the offset is wrong. Of course when the style is loaded from cache it is applied right away leaving no chance for javascript to misbehave.

---

Note: I also got a firstTop of 233 and a height of the div with id "header" of 195.875.

---

The solution? I don't know. <strike>I suspect parallax.js could allow some way to set a fixed initial offset.</strike> (there is no way to set the initial offset as the code stands).

You could look for a library that allows to check for the styles. (Note: reading the styles with javascript doesn't work, because they may be loaded but not applied).

<strike>If I were you, I would modify parallax.js (or try another version)</strike>. There is no need to modify parallax.js.

---

**EDIT 1**:

You should try to:

- Run your code with the [defer](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-defer) attribute.
- <strike>try to use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)</strike>

the idea is to make the browser execute the initialization of parallax "a bit later" so that it will apply css but not "too late" that the user will start interacting with the page.

**EDIT 2**:

- Place the styles before any javascript (or put javascript at the end of the document).
- Use `$(document).load` rather than `$(document).ready` to run parallax.js

Comment: Oh boy :( What would I need to modify in parallax.js? I have now changed the fixed header to normal. I believe it should be working for me, but it doesn't, parallax.js works in all of their examples... :|

I was really hoping this was my error so I could fix it.

Comment: @EdizArca In fact I've been modifying the demo of parallax.js to try to replicate the situation you encounter... with no luck so far. I wonder if it may be due to network latency because I'm testing locally. Anyway, I have forked parallax.js if i manage replicate the problem and modify the code to fix it I'll post a patch.

Comment: I have now, removed the parallax effect because of tight deadline. I will explore the possibilities of introducing it back to my design once the version one is launched. Thank you, if you have any further suggestions for me - please - I need them.

Comment: thanks once again. I do not have deep enough knowledge to do what you are doing. Hopefully, I will read through your patch and try to make sense out of it if you are successful.

Comment: @EdizArca I've been able to replicate the problem, I did it by placing the style after javascript in the header. And to fix it without moving the order of javascript and css, the solution was to use `load` instead of `ready`. Those are some of common suggestions to improve javascript performance, and in this case they also prevent the bug. So, I'll will no longer try to modify parallax, as for parallax goes all it needs is a bit of documentation, I've sent a message to the author about that.